# Security Alert popup when opening my projects in Delphi 12

Tags: delphi, delphi-ide, delphi-12-athens

When I open any project in Delphi 12, shortly after that I get multiple Security Alert popups. They all say the same thing and look the same:

> There is a problem with the site's security certificate: "US;DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA". Do you want to proceed?

[image: Delphi Security Alert]

It doesn't matter what I say, they will popup again (eventually). This also only started happening today.

It doesn't happen in Delphi 11.3, it only happens in Delphi 12.

It happens on all projects. Even a blank app.

Why am I getting this? What should I do? Reinstall Delphi 12?

Comment: Does this perhaps happen at the time when CodeInsight would otherwise display help information about procedure/function you are currently typing in? Or is this being shown when Delphi welcome page is being shown?

Comment: You're going to add more precise details, or contact EMBT support for assistance. There's not enough information in your post for us to be able to help.

Comment: It's actually quite random for when it shows.

Comment: Did you install 3rd party component or wizard or add-on to Delphi 12? If you did, remove them one by one and check if the alert still occurs.